# how to determine body tags in http request

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have a number of answer options that are being sent to the server with names "answer1", "answer2" etc. The number of answer options is set by the user in the browser. Is there any way to access their values without manually typing `req.body.answer1`, `req.body.answer2`?

Comment: use an array instead: `answer[]`, the object req.body.answer will be an array object

Comment: right. thanks. i changed the javascript so they all had the same name and it returned as an array. post it as the answer so i can accept it. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array instead: `answer[]`.

When appending the name with square brackets it will automatically be converted to an `Array` that you can access via `req.body.answer`.